# Identify Rank of date ranges from datetime column -- similar to previous post with an addition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have members, the group in which they belong, file type and datetimes in which they were active. I want to find out which members based on the group and file type rankings when there is a gap of 1 month or more.

| MID | Group | File Type | Create_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123A | EAM | Partial | 2022-01-16 12:23:28.474000000 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-03-01 10:41:15.500000000 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-04-15 10:41:15.500000000 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-05-26 10:41:15.500000000 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-09-20 10:41:15.500000000 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-10-05 10:41:15.500000000 |

This is the outcome I am looking for:

| MID | Group | File Type | Create_Date | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123A | EAM | Partial | 2022-01-16 12:23:28.474000000 | 1 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-03-01 10:41:15.500000000 | 2 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-04-15 10:41:15.500000000 | 2 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-05-26 10:41:15.500000000 | 2 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-09-20 10:41:15.500000000 | 3 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-10-05 10:41:15.500000000 | 3 |

Comment: It helps provide context for the solutions if you also post your attempted SQL query

Answer (score 2):

The CTE will get you the rank number, it will give a 1 when the date is bigger as 1 month or a new group is in the database else it is 0 as no change of rank is needed

The Outer select then needs only to sum the numbers up

```
WITH CTE As (SELECT
[MID], [Group], [File Type], [Create_Date]
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, LAG(Create_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY [Create_Date] ), [Create_Date]) > 1 
  OR DATEDIFF(MONTH, LAG(Create_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY [Create_Date] ), [Create_Date]) IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 ENd new_number
  FROM tab1)
SELECT 
  [MID], [Group], [File Type], [Create_Date],
SUM(new_number) OVER(PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY [Create_Date] ) [Rank]
FROM CTE
```

| MID | Group | File Type | Create_Date | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123A | EAM | Partial | 2022-01-16 12:23:28.473 | 1 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-03-01 10:41:15.500 | 2 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-04-15 10:41:15.500 | 2 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-05-26 10:41:15.500 | 2 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-09-20 10:41:15.500 | 3 |
| 123A | EAM | Full | 2022-10-05 10:41:15.500 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/btcirOgt)